# cv2.VideoWriter only generate empty file

Tags: python, opencv

When I tried to make a video by opencv2, I always end up having an empty file.
My python version is 2.7.13 and opencv version is 3.2.0. I am using Windows.
I tried the code by @Creyesk but still get an empty file.

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np

writer = cv2.VideoWriter('test1.avi',cv.CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'),25,  (640,480))
for i in range(1000):
    x = np.random.randint(255,size=(480,640)).astype('uint8')
    x = np.repeat(x,3,axis=1)
    x = x.reshape(480, 640, 3)
    writer.write(x)
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in your fourCC argument. I tried the following arguments and it worked:

`writer=cv2.VideoWriter("test1.avi", cv.CV_FOURCC(*'DIVX'), 25, (640,480))`

Comment: To be a little bit more specific, at least in my case it was the issue of a dimension mismatch. Trying to write frames with a different size than those given as a initialization parameter will cause them to be silently dropped (no error given).

Comment: I had to also remember to call writer.release() in the end, because otherwise the output file was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by @Gerard, there can be many reasons for this, since errors during construction of the writer or when adding frames, will not be raised as exceptions.

To check whether the constructor worked, you can call `writer.isOpened()` and check if it's `True`.

Then still errors can happen during writing frames, like when the frame does not have the same shape as passed to the constructor.